# Initilizing Add-in Application when creating excel add-in in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating an Excel Add-Ins for Office 2010.
Earlier i was doing code in Visual Studio 2010, .net framework 3.5 on ThisAddIn_Startup like

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  this.Application = (Excel.Application)Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.
  ExcelLocale1033Proxy.Wrap(typeof(Excel.Application), this.Application);

  CreateCommandBar();
}
```

But now the project is shifted on .net framework 4.0 then ExcelLocale1033Proxy is obsolete here.

What should i use here?
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will have to let go of ExcelLocale1033Proxy.

From [MSDN: Updating Excel and Word Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee712587.aspx)

> Projects that were created by using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools
>   for the Microsoft Office System instantiate the Excel
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application object by using the
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ExcelLocale1033Proxy class. This class
>   has been removed from the portion of the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for
>   Office Runtime that’s used for solutions that target the .NET
>   Framework 4 or the .NET Framework 4.5. Therefore, you must remove or
>   comment out the line of code that references this class.

Comment: then what i should use in stead of this.Application?

Comment: Or how to initilize this in stead of ExcelLocale1033Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Just i have to remove ExcelLocale1033Proxy to initialize the Application.
There is no need to do this in upgraded framework like .net framework 4.0 and above.
This is already initialized.